# How use Hibernate and MyBatis in the same application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, mybatis

I want to build an application using Hibernate and MyBatis integrate with Spring. In the prototype i've got to run them, but not toghether. My application context of Spring is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Document   : applicationContext-spring.xml
    Created on : 26 de diciembre de 2012, 15:49
    Author     : Pedro Fdez
    Description:
        Fichero de configuración de Spring
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd" default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.administracion.model.dao.implementations" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerHibernate"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />   

    <!-- ............................ -->
    <!-- Configuración de datasource -->
    <!-- ............................ -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- .......................... -->
    <!-- Configuración de Hibernate -->
    <!-- .......................... -->

    <!-- SessionFactory de Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactoryHibernate"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.administracion.model.pojos</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Gestor transaccional de Hibernate -->
    <bean id="txManagerHibernate"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryHibernate"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- ........................ -->
    <!-- Configuración Mybatis -->
    <!-- ........................ -->

    <!-- Gestor transaccional de MyBatis -->
    <bean id="txManagerMyBatis"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <tx:advice id="txAdviceMyBatis" transaction-manager="txManagerMyBatis">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="transactionPointCut"
            expression="execution(* com.administracion.model.dao.interfaces.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceMyBatis" pointcut-ref="transactionPointCut" />
    </aop:config>

    <!-- SessionFactory de MyBatis -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactoryMyBatis" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:conf/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MapperFactory de Mybatis -->
    <bean id="profesionMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactoryMyBatis" />
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.administracion.model.dao.mappers.IProfesionMapper" />
    </bean> 


    <bean id="profesionService" class="com.administracion.model.dao.implementations.ProfesionDaoImpl">
        <property name="profesionMapper" ref="profesionMapper" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Declaramos la exportación del servicio vía RMI -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="registryPort" value="${rmi.port.default}"/>
        <!-- Interface del servicio que exportamos -->
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.administracion.model.dao.interfaces.IProfesionDao"/>
        <!-- Nombre con que el servicio se va a llamar desde afuera -->
        <property name="serviceName" value="ProfesionService"/>
        <!-- Nombre del bean de la implementación que le hemos dado en el contexto de spring -->
        <property name="service" ref="profesionService"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In this way, each one have his own transaction manager and session factory. It's wrong because in a nested transaction can run several transactions, for example:

1. hibernate transaction
2. hibernate transaction
3. mybatis transaction
4. hibernate transaction

   If mybatis transaction make an exception, it does rollback, but not the hibernate one.

   He's readen int this forum a thread about how to share transaction between Hibernate and MyBatis, but I don't understand it.

   Can Somebody tell me about some link, or any information for fix this, please?

   Excuse me for my English. It's very bad.

   Thanks in advance.

   Pedro J.Fdez.
   Madrid. Spain.

Comment: From my understanding, you should be doing your transaction management on your service level not your DAO level and as long as your services bubble up exceptions properly the transaction management should work properly as your service class that uses your Hibernate DAO should be associated to your service class that uses Mybatis.  You should be aware though if you do use Hibernate caching and HQL you will end up with data discrepancies due to how query caching works with Hibernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling I've found a solution for it. Big problems, simple solutions.

```
<!-- 
<bean id="txManagerMyBatis"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
--> 
<tx:advice id="txAdviceMyBatis" transaction-manager="txManagerHibernate">
```

Basically, to comment de MyBatis transaction manager and to stick it to hibernate one.

I hope this help somebody.